# UnicodeEncodeError only with str(text) in Python

Tags: python, encoding

I'm reading a utf-8 encoded file. When I print the text directly, everything is fine. When i print the text from a class using `msg.__str__()` it works too.
But I really don't know how to print it only with `str(msg)` because this will always raise the error *"'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)"* if in the text is a umlaut.

Example Code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
 # encoding: utf-8

 import codecs from TempClass import TempClass

 file = codecs.open("person.txt", encoding="utf-8") message =
 file.read() #I am Mr. Händler.

 #works
 print message

 msg = TempClass(message)
 #works
 print msg.__str__()
 #works
 print msg.get_string()

 #error
 print str(msg)
```

And the class:

```
class TempClass(object):

def __init__(self, text):
    self.text = text

def get_string(self):
    return self.text

def __str__(self):
    return self.text
```

I tried to decode and encode the text in several ways but nothing works for me.

Help? :)

Edit: I am using Python 2.7.9

Comment: why would you want to do this? `print u'\xe4' -> ä
`

Comment: Why do you need to use `str(msg)`? `msg` is already a string. I can't seem to reproduce the problem (Python 3.4.2), either.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3,  the OP is using python2 which is very different to python3, also the type is unicode not str

Comment: @Matthias D. it works when you call the methods because you are passing a unicode str to your class not trying to decode to ascii as you are using `str(message)`

Comment: in python 2 this can be very helpful from \_\_future\_\_ import unicode_literals

Answer (score 1):

Because `message` (and `msg.text`) are not `str` but `unicode` objects. To call `str()` you need to specify utf-8 as the encoding again. Your `__str__` method should look like:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.text.encode('utf-8')
```

`unicode` can be implicitly encoded to `str` if it contains only ASCII characters, which is why you only see the error when the input contains an umlaut.

Comment: When i change it, the umlauts will not be printed.
They will be printed, if I also change the print line to `str(msg).decode('utf-8')`.
That's a strange way.

Comment: It worked for me, but my terminal encoding is UTF-8. Maybe yours isn't? Your extra `.decode('utf-8')` is converting it back to `unicode`, which would then get encoded properly for your terminal. Is there a reason for not using `unicode` (or Python 3)? `str` == `bytes` in Python 3, which means if you use it for text you're implicitly assuming ASCII encoding (which breaks when you have non-ASCII text).